# ADO.NET Data reader vs direct execution in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, sqldatareader

I have a strange problem at one of our clients. When the client runs a stored procedure using a ADO.NET SqlDataReader (called from a desktop application located on the same server as SqlServer) the SqlDataReader takes a lot of time to execute and eventualy times out. If I execute the same stored procedure (same parameters) from SSMS, it runs almost instantly (the tables involved are not very large).

The tables involved are indexed, the index were rebuild the night before.

If I run an "ALTER PROCEDURE procname..", then the SqlDatareader starts running instantly also, but only for some time (aroun 1-2 weeks), then it start hanging again.

The issue is happening only on the client server (which is Sql 2005), and if I take a backup of his DB, on our server is working without any issues.

Can you please suggest what measures should I take to prevent this?

Is recompiling the procedure at some interval of time a "normal" way to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to make a profile?
Just for test, try to clean the cache executing DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS and DBCC FREEPROCCACHE.
Just let me know the results.

Comment: The client has only an express version of Sql 20005 so I do not have access to profiler, and on my server the problem is not replicating. I will try the other suggestions to see what is happening. Thank you Ricardo!

Comment: I got. So each time you alter/create the procedure it works fast, right? Please, try the recompile option when declaring your procedure and make a test:
CREATE/ALTER (name) (parameters)  WITH RECOMPILE AS .....

You can also use with exec statement: EXECUTE procedure_name WITH RECOMPILE

Comment: I took your suggestion and I modified the sp. I will see if the client complains in the future. Please put this as an answer. Thanks a lot Ricardo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you alter/create the procedure it works fast, right?

You can use the recompile option when declaring your procedure and make a test:

`CREATE/ALTER (name) (parameters) WITH RECOMPILE AS`

You can also use with exec statement:

`EXECUTE procedure_name WITH RECOMPILE`

Hope it helps